# React Native iPad split screen components

Tags: ios, ipad, react-native, react-navigation

I want two screen components to be rendered side by side on iPad, just like below.

Is there a way to achieve this using react-navigation. I don't want slide-over left drawer. I want layout like default mail client on iPhone and iPad.

[image]

Comment: wix react-native-navigation v2 supports it ;)

Answer (score 0):

React navigation currently doesn't support this option natively. However, using drawer navigator and drawerType='permanent', as discussed in this github issue [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/6859). You can also checkout the official react-navigation example using the drawer navigator [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/MasterDetail.tsx).